# Converting Hex string to int32

Tags: c#

I got a string with Hex words, `STR = "48 3D E3 F4"`, (the spaces between the words don't matter). I want to make it first like that `I = 483DE3F4` but we can't put `D`,`E`,`F` in `int32`.

How can I make it, so that `I = 1212015604`?

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx? Getting lucky with google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `int.Parse(string, NumberStyles)` to parse hexadecimal :

```
int.Parse("48 3D E3 F4".Replace(" ", string.Empty), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```